# Does Ruby on Rails installation require write permissions to system directories and unfirewalled outbound access to the internet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I've got a specific, constructive question, which might perhaps be a more general question.

Specifically, I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails in a user directory, rather than on a system as a whole.  (Mac OS X).  The *compilations* of the latest ruby & libyaml works fine with these commands:

```
cd ruby-1.9.3-p392/ ; ./configure --prefix=/Users/username/local ; make install
cd yaml-0.1.4/ ; ./configure --prefix=/Users/username/local ; make install
```

and I have my LD_LIBRARY_PATH set to the local lib directory:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/Users/username/local/lib
```

But it won't let me install the rails gem:

```
gem install rails
/Users/username/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
```

Even though I have these in /Users/username/local/lib :

```
libyaml-0.2.dylib
libyaml.a
libyaml.dylib
libyaml.la
```

If I can get this specific question answered, I'll be unstuck.  *Is it the case that libyaml actually must be in /usr/local/lib?*

(Actually I'll still be stuck if the answer is yes but I'll know to give up!)

More generally, does Ruby on Rails installation require write permissions to system directories and unfirewalled outbound access to the internet?

Comment: You don't need root or special filesystem access to install Ruby.  You don't need any Internet access, either, although working in Ruby without convenient access to [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/) would be a painful experience.  I don't have a solution to your YAML problem, but it's probably not related to file permissions and it isn't related to net access.  If you can, use [RVM](http://rvm.io) or [rbenv](http://rbenv.org/) to manage Ruby versions in your Ruby installation.  Building by hand isn't worth it.

Answer (score 1):

To install Ruby on Rails in your home directory RVM is IMO the easiest way. Have a look at https://rvm.io/

I wrote a detailed description for the installation process:
http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/rails3-install-osx.html

Comment: Tried it, but... `rvm install 1.9.3` gives "Installing requirements for osx/10.7/x86_64, might require sudo password" - my goal is to *not* `sudo`.  It then ends on "Requested installation with homebrew libs, but homebrew is not available."  I don't want to install homebrew because that starts installing things in `/usr/local` -  I'd prefer self-contained installs (also, homebrew is another thing to install in itself.)  It's a bit too hairy having scripts zooming around the 'net installing various things in system directories!  Maybe ruby's best for when you have the run of the whole box...